# Deployment issue with Next.js 13 app on Vercel - "Cannot find module" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel

I'm facing a deployment issue with my Next.js 13 app on Vercel. I was trying to add the Parallel Routes feature of Next to my application. When I push the code to make a new pull request on my application's GitHub repository, the Vercel deployment of my branch completes successfully, but I encounter a 500 error. Upon checking the Vercel Logs, I found the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/.next/server/app/@landing/page.js'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at mod._resolveFilename (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.requirePage (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:88:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:49:73
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.loadComponentsImpl [as loadComponents] (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:49:26)
    at async NextNodeServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:600:36) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ],
  page: '/'
}
RequestId: 74d89b96-1db2-4832-a673-a834c04d20ba Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

It seems that the required module `/var/task/.next/server/app/@landing/page.js` cannot be found during the deployment process.

This is the content of the `page.jsx` file inside of the @landing folder:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Button from '@/components/Button';
import NavbarIcon from '@/components/NavbarIcons';

const LandingPage = () => {
  return (
    <main className="w-screen flex flex-col scrollbar-hide bg-white">
      <header className="w-full px-6 py-2 flex items-center drop-shadow-md">
        <nav className="w-full flex items-center">
          <ul className="w-full flex justify-between items-center drop-shadow-md">
            <li>
              <Link href={'/'}>
                <NavbarIcon icon='logo' />
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul className='flex gap-4'>
                <li>
                  <Link href={'/auth/login'}>
                    <Button bgColor="primary" isSolid={true}>
                      Iniciar Sesión
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link href={'/auth/register'}>
                    <Button bgColor="primary" isSolid={false}>
                      Crear Cuenta
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <article className="w-full h-screen"></article>
      <article className="w-full h-screen"></article>
      <article className="w-full h-screen"></article>
      <article className="w-full h-screen"></article>
    </main>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

This is the content of `layout.jsx` file:

```
import './globals.css';

import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

import Providers from './ReduxContext/provider';

import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Schedulo',
  description: 'Improve the way to contact services in our city.',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children, landing }) {
  //One way to handle session data is with next 'cookies' function, which use is similar to 'document.coockie'
  //We can choice to use other methods mor specific in future to handle users and auths, like firebase hooks.
  const coockieList = cookies();
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <>
            {coockieList.has('userToken') ? (
              <main className="relative w-screen max-w-[100vw] h-screen md:h-fit bg-white flex flex-col-reverse md:flex-row">
                <Navbar />
                {children}
              </main>
            ) : (
              landing
            )}
          </>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here is my `next.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Here are some additional details about my setup:

Next.js version: 13.12.4
Deployment platform: Vercel
Repository: GitHub

I have already tried the following:

1. Redeploying the branch from Vercel.
2. Verify that the build process completes without any errors locally.
3. Ensure that the necessary dependencies are installed correctly.
4. Verify that the application can run and works well locally.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's maybe because you are using an export default instead use the next docs recommended.

In their pages recommend export like :

```
export default function Page(){
  return (
  ...
)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).